# Game center issue with sending data

Tags: iphone, game-center

I'm working on a iOS multiplayer game which use Game Center.

When users login in Game Center and tap "play now" GC connect 4 players and game starts. The problem is that game is frequently freezing because some of the data are lost (I think this is the reason). Game usually works fine but sometimes data which are sent by server (server is some of the players) is lost and game freeze.

I use this function for sending data:

```
- (void)sendDataNSData *)data {
    NSError *error;

    BOOL success = [[GCHelper sharedInstance].match sendDataToAllPlayers:data withDataMode:GKMatchSendDataReliable errorerror];

    if (!success) {

        //NSLog(@"Error sending init packet");
        [self matchEnded];

    }
}
```

The problem is that matchend is not called so I believe that data is sent but it is lost.

Does anyone have similar issues and know how to fix it?

Comment: What about error parameter?

Comment: @Mert - there is no error. Sometimes client does not receive data package witout warning.

Comment: Do you use simulator or idevice? Game center api does not work properly on simulator.

Comment: @Mert - I 'm using real device.

Comment: If this is sent via UDP it's possible to lose packets. You might have to build your own confirmation protocol on top of GC?

Comment: @nielsbot - Yes, that is the only way to solve this problem.

Comment: I think this is related to net problems, maybe you are using UDP, even using TCP there is no warranty that server receive the data, I suggest the a alive connection, a customized contract with alive protocol

Comment: wait--you are specifying `GKMatchSendDataReliable`, so perhaps the problem lies somewhere else. if `sendDataToAllPlayers:withDataMode:error:` returns false that doesn't necessarily mean a networking error--it means the message could not be queued for transmission. Odd there's no error returned. You might simply retry if it returns `NO`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My users also complain that some data may be accidentally lost during the game. I wrote a [test app](https://github.com/rabovik/GKMatchPacketLostExample) and figured out that `GKMatchSendDataReliable` is not really reliable. On weak internet connection (e.g. EDGE) some packets are regularly lost without any error from the Game Center API.

So the only option is to add an extra transport layer for truly reliable delivery.

I wrote a simple lib for this purpose: [RoUTP](https://github.com/rabovik/RoUTP). It saves all sent messages until acknowledgement for each received, resends lost and buffers received messages in case of broken sequence.
In my tests combination "RoUTP + GKMatchSendDataUnreliable" works even beter than "RoUTP + GKMatchSendDataReliable" (and of course better than pure GKMatchSendDataReliable which is not really reliable).